# DHT11 data on arduino not outputting correctly

Tags: sensors, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am an engineering student using an arduino for the first time, and have gotten a little bit stuck. I am using an Arduino uno R3 to collect temperature and humidity data from 4 DHT11 sensors and upload it to an SD card on a data logging shield. I am trying to have it output a txt. file with all the recorded data timestamped using the RTC on the shield but unfortunately it is coming out wrong. Below is the output from 2 connected DHT11 sensors, and I don't know enough about the language to figure it out:

438,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
5564,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
10674,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
15784,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
20893,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
26001,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan
31111,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan

The code I am using is:

```
#include <SD.h>          // include the SD library
#include <SPI.h>         // include the SPI library
#include <DHT.h>         // include the DHT library

#define DHTPIN1 2        // pin for DHT11 #1
#define DHTPIN2 3        // pin for DHT11 #2
#define DHTPIN3 4        // pin for DHT11 #3
#define DHTPIN4 5        // pin for DHT11 #4
#define DHTTYPE DHT11    // DHT type is DHT11
DHT dht1(DHTPIN1, DHTTYPE);
DHT dht2(DHTPIN2, DHTTYPE);
DHT dht3(DHTPIN3, DHTTYPE);
DHT dht4(DHTPIN4, DHTTYPE);

File dataFile;           // create a file object to store data

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize SD card
  if (!SD.begin(10)) {
    Serial.println("SD card initialization failed");
    return;
  }
  // initialize DHT sensors
  dht1.begin();
  dht2.begin();
  dht3.begin();
  dht4.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // get timestamp
  unsigned long currentTime = millis();

  // read and save temperature and humidity data from all sensors
  float temperature1 = dht1.readTemperature();
  float humidity1 = dht1.readHumidity();
  float temperature2 = dht2.readTemperature();
  float humidity2 = dht2.readHumidity();
  float temperature3 = dht3.readTemperature();
  float humidity3 = dht3.readHumidity();
  float temperature4 = dht4.readTemperature();
  float humidity4 = dht4.readHumidity();

  // open data file in append mode
  dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if (dataFile) {
    // write timestamp and temperature/humidity data to file
    dataFile.print(currentTime);
    dataFile.print(",");
    dataFile.print(temperature1);
    dataFile.print(",");
    dataFile.print(humidity1);
    dataFile.print(",");
    dataFile.print(temperature2);
    dataFile.print(",");
    dataFile.print(humidity2);
    dataFile.print(",");
    dataFile.print(temperature3);
    dataFile.print(",");
    dataFile.print(humidity3);
    dataFile.print(",");
    dataFile.print(temperature4);
    dataFile.print(",");
    dataFile.println(humidity4);
    dataFile.close();
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Error opening datalog.txt");
  }

  // wait 5 seconds before taking next measurement
  delay(5000);
}
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

I tried initially with one DHT11 sensor and got the same format of output, so thought adding more sensors would help clear things up but that has not been the case, I dont know where the issue lies.